# How do compute lowest eigenvalue using Arpack in C language

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-solver, arpack

Hi I have a problem to calculate lowest eigenvalue in non-symmetric matrix using Arpack, because my matrix is very complicated and even I have a lot of trouble to made a matrix - vector multiplication.

But the Arpack can calculate only the largest magnitude with the simple matrix - vector multiplication, what I know to get the lowest eigenvalues I need to do inverse of these matrix, but my matrix is to large to do the inverse (I don't have enough memory to read whole matrix).

I'm new with that and it is really hard for me to read an example in FORTRAN and learn from them.
Can anyone direct me what I can do to find the lowest eigenvalues using Arpack in C?

I will paste my code to show what I have.

```c
     BLASINT ido = 0;
      char const* bmat = "I";
      BLASINT N = u*mx;
      char const* which = "LM";
      BLASINT nev = 20;
      double tol = 0.000001;
      double *resid = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double)*(N));
      BLASINT ncv = 10*nev+1;
      double *V = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double)*(N*ncv));
      BLASINT ldv = N;
      int *iparam = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*(11));
      int *ipntr = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*(14));
      double *workd = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double)*(3*N));
      double *workl = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double)*(3*ncv*ncv+6*ncv));
      BLASINT lworkl  = 3*ncv*ncv+6*ncv;
      BLASINT info = 0;

      bool rvec = true;
      char howmny[] = "A";
      int *select = (int*) malloc((ncv)*sizeof(int));
      double *dr = (double*) malloc((nev+1)*sizeof(double));
      double *di = (double*) malloc((nev+1)*sizeof(double));
      double *zz = (double*) malloc(((N+1)*(nev+1))*sizeof(double));
      BLASINT ldz = N+1;
      double sigmar=0.;
      double sigmai=0.;
      double *workev = (double*) malloc((3*ncv)*sizeof(double));




      double tmpb = 0.;
      size_t j = 0.;
      size_t i = 0.;

      double tmp = 0.;
      double tmp1 = 0.;
      double tmp2 = 0.;
      double tmp3 = 0.;
      double tmp4 = 0.;
      double tmp5 = 0.;
      size_t z = 0.;

      double ttmp = 0.;


      for(size_t i=0; i<3*N; i++ ){
        workd[i] = 0;
      }

      for(size_t i=0; i<3*ncv*ncv+6*ncv; i++ ){
        workl[i] = 0;
      }

      iparam[0] = 1;
      iparam[2] = 10*N;                                                         //maxiumum iteration
      iparam[3] = 1;
      iparam[4] = 0;                                                            // number of ev found by arpack.
      iparam[6] = 1;



double iter=0.;

do{

iter++;

dnaupd_c(&ido, bmat , N , which , nev , tol , resid , ncv , V , ldv , iparam , ipntr , workd , workl , lworkl ,  &info );


// Matrix - vector multiplication


        tmpb = 0.;
        j = 0.;
        i = 0.;

      // Bozons
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(nthreads) default(none) private(i,j,tmpb) shared(mx,h,workd,ipntr,mmtrix)
        for(j = 0; j < mx; j++){
          tmpb = 0.;
          for(i = 0; i < mx; i++){
            tmpb = tmpb + h[j*mx+i]*workd[ipntr[0]-1 + i] ;
          }
          mmtrix[j] = tmpb;
        }


#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(nthreads) default(none) private(i,j,tmpb) shared(mx,h1,workd,ipntr,mmtrix)
        for(j = 0; j < mx; j++){
          tmpb = 0.;
          for(i = 0; i < mx; i++){
            tmpb = tmpb + h1[j*mx+i]*workd[ipntr[0]-1 + mx + i] ;
          }
          mmtrix[mx+j] = tmpb;
        }


#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(nthreads) default(none) private(i,j,tmpb) shared(mx,h2,workd,ipntr,nn,mmtrix)
        for(j = 0; j < mx; j++){
          tmpb = 0.;
          for(i = 0; i < mx; i++){
            tmpb = tmpb + h2[j*mx+i]*workd[ipntr[0]-1 + i] ;
          }
          mmtrix[(2*nn+2)*mx+j] = tmpb;
        }


#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(nthreads) default(none) private(i,j,tmpb) shared(mx,h3,workd,ipntr,nn,mmtrix)
        for(j = 0; j < mx; j++){
          tmpb = 0.;
          for(i = 0; i < mx; i++){
            tmpb = tmpb + h3[j*mx+i]*workd[ipntr[0]-1 + mx + i] ;
              }
          mmtrix[(2*nn+2)*mx + mx + j] = tmpb;
        }



        tmp = 0.;
        tmp1 = 0.;
        tmp2 = 0.;
        tmp3 = 0.;
        tmp4 = 0.;
        tmp5 = 0.;
        z = 0.;



  for(z = 1 ; z <= nn ; z++){

#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(nthreads) default(none) private(i) shared(mx,nF1_t,nF_sqrt_1_t,nF_den_t,nF_sqrt_ff,nF_sqrt_ff_1,nF_den,z)
    for(i = 0; i < mx ; i++){                   // these function changed for every z
      nF1_t[i] = nF_sqrt_ff[(z-1)*mx + i];
      nF_sqrt_1_t[i] = nF_sqrt_ff_1[(z-1)*mx + i];
      nF_den_t[i] = nF_den[(z-1)*mx + i];
    }


    gbf_nb_nf( mx, gbf, x, gbf3, den1_x_sqrt, nF1_t);               // these function changed for every z
    matrix_2(gbf3, mx, h4);                         // these function changed for every z

    mu_calka_nF_1(x, mx, nn, dx, gbf, mu_nB_f, den1_x, nF_sqrt_1_t, nF1_t, tr_f_1, ms, nF_den_t);   // these function changed for every z
    matrix_fer_1(mx, kin, gbf4, ms, h5, kin_f, tr_f, mu_nB_f, mass);                    // these function changed for every z




#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(nthreads) default(none) private(i,j,tmp,tmp1,tmp2,tmp3,tmp4,tmp5) shared(mx,h4,h5,workd,ipntr,nn,mmtrix,z)
          for(j = 0; j < mx; j++){
            tmp=0.;
            tmp1=0.;
            tmp2=0.;
            tmp3=0.;
            tmp4=0.;
            tmp5=0.;
          for(i = 0; i < mx; i++){
              tmp = tmp + h4[j*mx + i]*workd[ipntr[0]-1 + 2*z*mx + i];          // Row Fermion
              tmp1 = tmp1 - h4[j*mx + i]*workd[ipntr[0]-1 + (2*z+1)*mx + i];
              tmp2 = tmp2 + h4[j*mx + i]*workd[ipntr[0]-1 + i];                 // Column Fermion
              tmp3 = tmp3 - h4[j*mx + i]*workd[ipntr[0]-1 + mx + i];
              tmp4 = tmp4 + h5[j*mx + i]*workd[ipntr[0]-1 + 2*z*mx + i];        // Diag Fermion
              tmp5 = tmp5 - h5[j*mx + i]*workd[ipntr[0]-1 + (2*z+1)*mx + i];
            }
            mmtrix[2*z*mx + j] = tmp;                                           // Row
            mmtrix[(2*z+1)*mx + j] = tmp1;
            mmtrix[(2*nn+2)*mx + 2*z*mx + j] = tmp;
            mmtrix[(2*nn+2)*mx + (2*z+1)*mx + j] = tmp1;
            mmtrix[6*(z-1)*mx + 2*(2*nn+2)*mx +  j] = tmp2;                     // Column and Diag
            mmtrix[6*(z-1)*mx + 2*(2*nn+2)*mx + mx + j] = tmp3;
            mmtrix[6*(z-1)*mx + 2*(2*nn+2)*mx + 2*mx + j] = tmp4;
            mmtrix[6*(z-1)*mx + 3*mx + 2*(2*nn+2)*mx +  j] = tmp2;
            mmtrix[6*(z-1)*mx + 3*mx + 2*(2*nn+2)*mx + mx + j] = tmp3;
            mmtrix[6*(z-1)*mx + 3*mx + 2*(2*nn+2)*mx + 2*mx + j] = tmp5;
          }
        }



ttmp = 0.;

#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(nthreads) default(none) private(i,j,ttmp) shared(mx,mmtrix1,nn,mmtrix)
        for(j = 0; j < mx; j++){                                                // 2 rows
          ttmp = 0.;
          for(i = 0; i < (2*nn+2); i++){
            ttmp = ttmp + mmtrix[i*mx + j];
          }
          mmtrix1[j] = ttmp;
        }

#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(nthreads) default(none) private(i,j,ttmp) shared(mx,mmtrix1,nn,mmtrix)
        for(j = 0; j < mx; j++){
          ttmp = 0.;
          for(i = 0; i < (2*nn+2); i++){
            ttmp = ttmp + mmtrix[(2*nn+2)*mx + i*mx + j];
          }
          mmtrix1[mx + j] = ttmp;
        }



  for(z = 1 ; z <= nn ; z++){                                                   // Rest

#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(nthreads) default(none) private(i,j,ttmp) shared(mx,mmtrix1,nn,mmtrix,z)
        for(j = 0; j < mx; j++){
                   ttmp = 0.;
                   for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                     ttmp = ttmp + mmtrix[2*(2*nn+2)*mx + (z-1)*6*mx + i*mx + j];
                   }
                   mmtrix1[2*z*mx + j] = ttmp;
                 }

#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(nthreads) default(none) private(i,j,ttmp) shared(mx,mmtrix1,nn,mmtrix,z)
         for(j = 0; j < mx; j++){
                    ttmp = 0.;
                    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                      ttmp = ttmp + mmtrix[2*(2*nn+2)*mx + 3*mx + (z-1)*6*mx + i*mx + j];
                    }
                    mmtrix1[(2*z+1)*mx + j] = ttmp;
                  }
}

// End of the matrix - vector multiplication

#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(nthreads) default(none) private(j) shared(mx,u,workd,ipntr,mmtrix1)
for(j = 0; j < mx*u ; j++){
  workd[ipntr[1]-1 + j] = mmtrix1[j];   //writing the result
}


}while (ido == 1 || ido == -1);



if (info < 0 || iparam[4] < nev) {
  printf("Error in saupd: iparam[4] %d, nev %d, info %d\n", iparam[4], nev, info);
  return 1;
}


dneupd_c(rvec, howmny, select, dr, di, zz, ldz, sigmar, sigmai, workev,
          bmat, N, which, nev, tol, resid, ncv, V, ldv, iparam, ipntr,
          workd, workl, lworkl, &info);



if (info < 0) {
  printf("Error in seupd: info %d\n", info);
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: These code is work for largest magnitude, but when I'm choose which = SM the program never end